# image matching using sift algorithm with global context and local shaped based descriptor

Tags: sift

Can anyone explain me how the sift algorithm is working using numerical values..I am searching over Internet but the thing I am getting is only input and output of the sift algorithm but the thing I want that what actually is going on and how,they are calculating keypoints using,global descriptors and how the match between two image is done.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can start by reading the scientific paper.

http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~malik/cs294/lowe-ijcv04.pdf